# How many line segments are determined by $n$ vertices of a $n$-gon?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

> How many line segments are determined by $n$ vertices of a $n$-gon? Of these, how many are diagonals?

I made a table of values to try to find a pattern:
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & \text{Line Segments} & \text{Diagonals}\\
\hline
3 & \qquad\quad3 & 0 \\
4 & \qquad\quad6 & 2 \\
5 & \qquad\quad10 & 5
\end{array}

Using this table I got the formula for the number of line segments as $\dfrac{n(n-1)}2$ and the formula for the number of diagonals as $n-3+\dfrac{(n-2)(n-3)}2$. Is this correct?

Comment: Check your 5-9 again:)  (and, in general, maybe think about $1+2+\cdots n-1=n(n-1)/2$)

Comment: @JohnForkosh Fixed the mistake, please check the updated version=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line segment must be either an edge or a diagonal, and since $n$-gon has $n$ edges, the number of line segments must be $n+d_n$, where $d_n$ is the number of diagonals (in the $n$-gon). Eyeballing it, we can clearly see that you're missing one diagonal on the case $n=5$.

That said, one can find the number of line segments quite easily using combinatorics. Since no three points of an $n$-gon are collinear, a line segment is entirely defined by two of the vertices of an $n$-gon. **Hint:** use binomial numbers!

Comment: I can't seem to figure out the formula for the number of diagonals...

Comment: @suomynonA think about it iteratively, if you already know #diagonals(n) for an n-gon, how many additional diagonals are generated when you add an ${(n+1)}^{th}$ point, giving you #diagonals(n+1). This is just a more complicated version of what you did for #lines(n).

Comment: I thought $(n-3)(n-2)$ but that only worked for $n=3,4$

Comment: You can definitely count the number of diagonals using combinatorics, but it's easier to go straight for the number of line segments.

Comment: I think I got it